# Command works through terminal but not through python system call

Tags: python, system, subprocess, pipe

I'm trying to make a system call from a python code to the Boxer text parser program and I find that the following set of statements doesn't work. It doesn't give me any error but I don't see any output file created. When I run the same command on the terminal, the output file does get created.

```
from subprocess import call
candcStr = 'echo "Every Man Walks" | /home/candc-1.00/bin/candc --models /home/candc-1.00/models/boxer --output /tmp/test.ccg' 
args = shlex.split(candcStr)
call(args)
```

When I run the above code, the console shows

```
Every Man Walks | /home/candc-1.00/bin/candc --models /home/candc-1.00/models/boxer --output /tmp/test.ccg
```

It appears as though the pipe redirection isn't working. Does anyone know how I can fix this ? Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `shell=True` for the shell to interpret the command, and most of all the pipe:

```
call(args, shell=True)
```